# Pass-through constructor for std::optional argument

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

Is there a way, idiomatically, to provide a constructor/conversion which takes a `std::optional<T>` and returns a `std::optional<U>`? For instance, ideally I would love some kind of syntax like

```cpp
#include <optional>

struct MyInt { 
  explicit MyInt(int i_) : i{i_} {}
  // magic here?...
  int i;
};

int main()
{
  MyInt i1 = MyInt(1);
  std::optional<int> opt_i{};
  std::optional<MyInt> i2 = MyInt(opt_i);  // empty
  opt_i = 3;
  std::optional<MyInt> i3 = MyInt(opt_i);  // contains MyInt(3)
}
```

I believe this is not currently possible. What are my best options?

Comment: You mean C++23 [`std::optional::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/transform)?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Hmm, I guess that works but it's pretty ugly... `auto i1 = std::optional<int>(); auto i2 = i1.transform([](auto&& i){return MyInt(std::forward<decltype(i)>(i));});`

Comment: But I guess no one has ever accused C++ of being pretty...

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstand something, but what's wrong with the bog standard `std::optional` constructor? `std::optional<MyInt> i2{opt_i};` just works.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI That is the best answer, yes. Unfortunately I simplified the question to the point of triviality. My second attempt is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77868389/pass-through-constructor-for-stdoptional-arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::optional` already provides the desired conversion via constructors (4) and (5) listed here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional.

```
#include <optional>

struct MyInt { 
  explicit MyInt(int i_) : i{i_} {}
  // magic here?...
  int i;
};

int main()
{
  MyInt i1 = MyInt(1);
  std::optional<int> opt_i{};
  std::optional<MyInt> i2{opt_i};
  opt_i = 3;
  std::optional<MyInt> i3{opt_i};
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W3vTYrThj)

I haven't seen before `std::optional::transform` that is suggested in the other answer. I suppose it would be needed when `MyInt` itself does not provide a conversion from `int` but you want to transform it anyhow.

Comment: Ah, I see... I simplified the example too much. This won't work for my actual example. Let me edit the question...

Comment: @kc9jud you should not edit hte question after receiving answers. This answers the question you did ask here. If you want to ask a different question you should open a new question.

Comment: @kc9jud well ok, I wouldnt mind too much. But note that invalidating answer that are already posted isnt nice. If you change your quesiton so that this answer doesnt apply anymore I can delete it and my effort is lost. Anyhow it was much more than a tiny edit on your code, so just go ahead. jsut dont forget to ping me, tahts the least you should do when your edit makes an answer not uptodate anymore

Comment: Should I just delete the question and ask a new one instead?

Comment: @kc9jud why would you delete the question?!?

Comment: Because it's a trivial question which is obviously answered in the docs... RTFM and all that.

Comment: you asked the question so its worth asking

Comment: Well, I didn't actually ask the question I meant to ask, and the question I did ask wasn't worth asking. I'll post a new question and edit this one with a link to that one.

Comment: some considered it worthwhile to write an answer. And, again, its not nice of you to decide that this effort others put into it no matter how tiny it was should be deleted.

Comment: @kc9jud btw I am not arguing to defend my answer. I would loose neither lots of rep nor lots of work, but I would raise the same points if the answer would be by someone else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256661/discussion-between-kc9jud-and-463035818-is-not-an-ai).